# How to save a TM VCorpus with custom meta in R

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I am saving a TM corpus in R.

```
writeCorpus(as.character(thecrp), dirdst, filenames = NULL)
```

Everything is fine until I get an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : no method applicable for meta applicable to an object of class "character"
```

NB. I have added three custom meta fields in each document in the corpus.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# Create corpus from a folder of documents on disk
thetxts <- readtext(pthtxt, cache = FALSE)
thecrp <- corpus(thetxts)
# Add docvars (= columns)
# Reference
# NOTE: Add Meta to the corpus
meta(thecrp, tag = "doctyp", type = "corpus") <- "Reports, 2018"
# NOTE: Add Meta to each of the documents
for (i in 1:length(thecrp)){
    # ID derived from the name of the file (withdraw .txt)
    meta(thecrp[[i]], tag = "id", type = "indexed") <- gsub("\\.txt", "", meta(thecrp[[i]], tag = "id", type = "indexed"))
    # constants
    meta(thecrp[[i]], tag = "author", type = "indexed") <- "author"
    meta(thecrp[[i]], tag = "type", type = "indexed") <- "individual"
    meta(thecrp[[i]], tag = "prov", type = "indexed") <- "ocr"
}
# Then I perform usual and **mildly** transformative actions on the corpus
...
# Then I save it to disk: the **error occurs here**
dirdst <- "~/test"
writeCorpus(as.character(thecrp), dirdst, filenames = NULL)
```

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help. As it stands now it is difficult to tell what might cause the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Here you go:

Comment: Changing `writeCorpus(as.character(thecrp), dirdst, filenames = NULL)` to `writeCorpus(thecrp, dirdst, filenames = NULL)` will remove the error and write the files to disk. But it will be without all the meta information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was following the advice on TM documentation.